# JQuery UI Dialog Modal - Re-showing dialog can't edit text

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a div:

```
<div id="mproEmailAccountPopUp"></div>
```

I declare a Dialog

```
var popupdiv = $( '#mproEmailAccountPopUp' );
popupdiv.dialog({
    width: 650,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false
});
```

I then get some html form stuff (this works fine) from a server and update the dialog content:

```
function ShowEdit(accountId) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "<%=EmailHandler %>?action=GetEmailAccountEdit",
        data: { accountId: accountId },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Success GetEmailAccountEdit");

            popupdiv.html(result);
            popupdiv.dialog("open");
            //popupdiv.dialog( "moveToTop" )

        }
    });
}
```

This works beautifully the first time, but if you press the close button, and then recall the function. The dialog is updated with the new html, but you can't type in ANY of the text boxes. I have narrowed it down to the modal overlay (as it works with modal:false). The z-index seems to be 1 less than the modal form, and I have even deleted (via firebug) the modal overlay div, but I can still not edit the text boxes.

If I turn modal:false then it works fine, modal:true is causing these problems.

As you can see, i have tried the "moveToTop" method, no effect.

I have also tried destroying the popup, and reinitialising it entirely from within the ShowEdit function.

Anyone have any clue about what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Where are the textboxes? ... and what kind of HTML are you trying to insert in the dialog?

Comment: Just for completion, it was caused by loading several versions of the above code, and the popup was applied to more than one div. Once the names were made unique, then it worked ok.

Comment: it was loading the same form from Asp.net via a webservice call. Same form, different data (user j-query tabs) but in loading the form from the webservice, ASP.NET does not know the context of the page, and therefore could not make the ID's unique, in fact, it gave them the same ones each time...